# Can't launch gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, gconf

Running on Ubuntu 13.04, GNOME Shell 3.6.3.1.

If I start it from terminanator, I get this error:

```
mia@mavrica:~$ gnome-terminal
Failed to summon the GConf demon; exiting. Failed to activate configuration server: Process /usr/local/libexec/gconfd-2 exited with status 127
```

Comment: This might be your issue -->https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gconf2/+bug/328575

Comment: @Stormvirux That is one really old bug report. It might be better for the OP to report a new bug.